# Facing Problem in Tree View in C# windows form with details below:

Tags: c#, winforms, search, treeview

Whenever I tried to get the value from `treeview` in which I get the data from database on `Get Data` button and try to display it on `datagridview` by checking the checkbox of `treeview` node it will not display the details of that node in `datagridview` on `Search` button.

`Treeview` after getting the data from Database on `Get Data` Button:

[image]

**So, I want now is that whenever I check the `treeview` node and then click on `Search` button it must show all details of that node in `datagridview`.**

My Code of this `Winform`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace My_Work
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Get_Data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string conStr = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Data;Data Source=MY-PC";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            con.Open();
            string query = "select ItemNo,UnitePrice from Product_Item";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                TreeNode n = new TreeNode(sdr["ItemNo"].ToString());
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(n);
                n.Nodes.Add(sdr["UnitePrice"].ToString());
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
        {
            string conStr = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Data;Data Source=MY-PC";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            con.Open();
            string nodeName = e.Node.ToString().Replace("TreeNode: ", string.Empty);
            if (e.Node.Parent != null)
            {
                string q = "select * from Product_Item where UnitePrice='" + nodeName + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }

        private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string conStr = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Data;Data Source=MY-PC";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            con.Open();
            if(treeView1.CheckBoxes == true)
            {
                string nodeCheck = treeView1.CheckBoxes.ToString();
                string q = "select * from Product_Item where ItemNo='" + nodeCheck + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the code in which I want to get the details of check node but I cannot get the details of that node.**

```
private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string conStr = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Data;Data Source=MY-PC";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        con.Open();
        if(treeView1.CheckBoxes == true)
        {
            string nodeCheck = treeView1.CheckBoxes.ToString();
            string q = "select * from Product_Item where ItemNo='" + nodeCheck + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
}
```

Database Table `Product_Item`:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [TreeView.CheckBoxes Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.checkboxes?view=net-5.0) returns a Boolean telling you whether the treeview displays checkboxes. You cannot get the required SQL condition out of it, but you can get the item numbers of the checked items with

```cs
var itemNums = new List<string>();
foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
{
    if (node.Checked) {
        itemNums.Add(node.Text);
    }
}
```

Now, you must create a SQL condition from this list. Assuming that these numbers are stored in a `int` column, we can create a list of numbers with

```cs
string numList = String.Join(", ", itemNums);
```

and then use this to build the SQL statement:

```cs
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Product_Item WHERE ItemNo IN (" + numList  + ")";
```

If, however, the item numbers are stored in a text column, then we must write

```cs
string numList = String.Join("', '", itemNums);
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Product_Item WHERE ItemNo IN ('" + numList  + "')";
```

This produces conditions looking like `WHERE ItemNo IN (1, 7, 9)` or
`WHERE ItemNo IN ('1', '7', '9')`.